# SQL Server Allocation of amount in bill

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have the following tables

```
LINEID   BILL   Total Amount     Allocated Amount
1         1         100             
2         1         200
3         2         250

PAYID    BILL    Paid Amount
1         1         250
2         2         100
```

I need to allocate the Paid amoount on the first table based on the bill. I know that I can use the cursor with WHILE loop and allocate - is there a better way to do this?

Result should be

```
LINEID   BILL   Total Amount     Allocated Amount
1         1         100             100
2         1         200         150
3         2         250         100
```

Comment: what do you want your result to be?

Comment: The following result in same table
` 
LINEID   BILL   Total Amount     Allocated Amount
1         1         100             100
2         1         200      150
3         2         250     100
`
- Shankar.

Comment: Just edited to add the result.

Comment: What happens if someone pays for Bill 1 with two different payment methods or at different times ? How will you record the AllocatedAmount. You may have a design issue here.

Comment: There is no different payment methods (only one). I have to select records if the total amount != allocated amount based on the bill payments & allocate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH  cl AS
(select o.LINEID, o.BILL, o.[Total Amount], 
(select SUM([Total Amount]) from bills t where o.BILL = t.BILL and o.LINEID >= t.LINEID) as 'sum_total_ammount'
from bills o inner join payment p on o.BILL = p.BILL)

select o.LINEID, o.BILL, o.[Total Amount], 
case when p.[Paid Amount] >= sum_total_ammount then o.[Total Amount] 
else (o.[Total Amount] - sum_total_ammount + p.[Paid Amount]) end as 'Allocated Amount'
from cl o inner join payment p on o.BILL = p.BILL
and (o.[Total Amount] - sum_total_ammount + p.[Paid Amount]) > 0
```

Here's a Demo on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60b15/1/0).

Comment: Thank you .. it works.. I modified the code a bit more to suit the table needs, but got the logic.