# Sql - SELECT rows until the sum of a row is a certain value

Tags: sql-server

I've seen other similar questions arround here, but they don't quite meet my needs, at least that's what I think.

I have a [reciepts] table with the following columns:
reciept_id,
customer_id,
ammount
...

Lets Say:

I have 5 unpayed reciepts from customer 1:

```
reciept_id: 1 | Ammount: 110€

reciept_id: 2 | Ammount: 110€

reciept_id: 3 | Ammount: 130€

reciept_id: 4 | Ammount: 110€

reciept_id: 5 | Ammount: 190€
```

So, customer 1, pays me 220€.

Now I need to select the oldest reciepts, until this 220€ sum is met, but only in a straight order, like (reciept 1 + reciept 2) and NOT like (reciept 1 + reciept 4).

Can you help me with the best query for this, or at least point me the best answer out there?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: MySQL or SQL-server?

Comment: what is the case for a row which is higher than `220`?

Comment: Sorry, it's SQL-Server @Raymond Nijland

Comment: @Badiparmagi, if there is a row higher than 220, no value should be returned in the query. Thanks for that question.

Comment: I would create another column with the 'amount paid'. The existing 'Ammount' column I would call 'amount due'. Procedure: Pick the oldest receipt which isn't completely paid, and paid as much as you can: Add to 'amount due' and subtract from 'amount paid'. And so on, step by step, until no money is left to pay an amount due. I wouldn't worry about this taking multiple queries.

Comment: Are the euro sign's really in the database?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - My client does have that structure in the real table and your answer makes all sense, but my client's rule is, "If you can find a value(rows) for that sum, you can change the payed ammount to 100%, but if you cant find a value in that query, no reciept should be charged, and a manual process will take care after that." Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @RaymondNijland - No, just in the example, the column is set as decimal

Comment: may be helps you to build a logic , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860284/sql-server-allocation-of-amount-in-bill

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the sum will match the rows in sequence. Following query will work.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(Reciept_Id INT , Amount INT)
INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT * 
FROM   (
         VALUES (1, 110),(2,110),(3,130),(4,110),(5,190)
       ) t (Reciept_Id, Amount) 

--Query

SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
    Reciept_Id, 
    Amount,
    SUM(Amount) OVER(ORDER BY Reciept_Id ROWS 
       BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Total
FROM @Table
) T
WHERE T.Total <= 220
```

**Output:**

```
 Reciept_Id   Amount    Total
-----------   -------  ----------
    1          110      110
    2          110      220
```

**Note :** Query will work in SQL-Server 2012 and higher versions.