# Alternative: Sql - SELECT rows until the sum of a row is a certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

My question is very similar to my previous one posted here:
[Sql - SELECT rows until the sum of a row is a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48746563/sql-select-rows-until-the-sum-of-a-row-is-a-certain-value)

To sum it up, I need to return the rows, until a certain sum is reached, but the difference this time, is that, I need to find the best fit for this sum, I mean, It doesn't have to be sequential. For example:

Let's say I have 5 unpaid receipts from customer 1:

```
Receipt_id: 1 | Amount: 110€
Receipt_id: 2 | Amount: 110€
Receipt_id: 3 | Amount: 130€
Receipt_id: 4 | Amount: 110€
Receipt_id: 5 | Amount: 190€
```

So, customer 1 ought to pay me 220€.

Now I need to select the receipts, until this 220€ sum is met and it might be in a straight order, like (receipt 1 + receipt 2) or not in a specific order, like (receipt 1 + receipt 4), any of these situations would be suitable.

I am using SQL Server 2016.

Any additional questions, feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: This is a combinatorial problem (specifically a type of bin-packing) and not really suitable to a relational database.  It is possible, but not the best tool for the job.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was afraid of that answer, I've been trying to use vb.net to process the raw data returned from SQL and it is a sea of formulas and decisions to find the best suitable result, but so far with no perfect answer, so I decided to try and put SQL to do the hard work.

Comment: +1 @GordonLinoff - Rui 'bin-packing' is a google-able term with variations and approaches on solving them.

Comment: There are too many "what ifs" for this question to be answered, and too many to ask them all in a comment.   You could take a shot at anticipating them all, but otherwise, this question is unclear in its current form.

Comment: It is "receipt" not "reciept".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should solve it.

> It is a quite dangerous query (containing a recursive CTE), so please be careful!

You can find some documentation here: https://www.essentialsql.com/recursive-ctes-explained/

```
  WITH the_data as (
      SELECT * 
      FROM (
           VALUES (1, 1, 110),(1, 2,110),(1, 3,130),(1, 4,110),(1, 5,190),
           (2, 1, 10),(2, 2,20),(2, 3,200),(2, 4,190)
             ) t (user_id, receipt_id, amount)
  ), permutation /* recursive used here */ as (
      SELECT 
          user_id,
          amount as sum_amount, 
          CAST(receipt_id as varchar(max)) as visited_receipt_id,
          receipt_id as max_receipt_id,
          1 as i
      FROM the_data
      WHERE amount > 0 -- remove empty amount

      UNION ALL 

      SELECT 
          the_data.user_id, 
          sum_amount + amount as sum_amount,
          CAST(concat(visited_receipt_id, ',', CAST(receipt_id as varchar))as varchar(max)) as visited_receipt_id,
          receipt_id as max_receipt_id , 
          i + 1 
      FROM the_data
      JOIN permutation
        ON the_data.user_id = permutation.user_id
      WHERE i < 1000 -- max 1000 loops, means any permutation with less than 1000 different receipts 
        and receipt_id > max_receipt_id -- in order that sum in komutatif , we can check the sum in any unique order ( here we take the order of the reciept_id in fact we do not produce any duplicates )  
        -- AND sum_amount + amount <= 220 -- ignore everything that is bigger than the expected value (optional)
  ) 
  SELECT * 
  FROM permutation
  WHERE sum_amount = 220
```

in order to select only one combination per user_id, replace the last three lines of the previous query by

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, row_number() OVER (partition by user_id order by random() ) as r  
    FROM permutation
    WHERE sum_amount = 220
) as t
WHERE r = 1
```

Comment: by dangerous you mean, risk of too much memory usage?

Comment: by dangerous i mean, for each receipt the query search for many combination up to 1000 ( see i ), in the case of my example it create for example 46 rows, to find all combinations.
see this fiddle to understand whats happen http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/5135/0

in case you are running it only for one user separately, and apply the filter "AND sum_amount + amount <= 220" and "i<10" it is saver,

Answer (score 0):

IF your target is to sum only 2 receipts in order to reach your value, this could be a solution:

```
DECLARE @TARGET   INT = 220 --SET YOUR TARGET
      , @DIFF     INT
      , @FIRSTVAL INT

SET @FIRSTVAL = (
         SELECT TOP 1 AMOUNT
         FROM myRECEIPTS
         ORDER BY RECEIPT_ID ASC
)

SELECT   TOP 1 *
FROM     myRECEIPTS
WHERE    AMOUNT = @TARGET - @FIRSTVAL
ORDER BY RECEIPT_ID ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will do it:

```
    declare @sum1 int
    declare @numrows int
    set @numrows= 1
    set @sum1 =0
    while (@sum1 < 10)
    begin
     select top (@numrows) @sum1=sum(sum1) from receipts
     set  @numrows +=1
     end
  select top(@numrows) * from receipts
```