# SQL Trigger - Allocation Amount

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

i need to create a complex trigger in my database.

I try to explain my problem:
In my database I have 3 tables: Cash table, invoice table and installment payment table. Now I need to create a trigger. When I enter a payment in the collection table, the trigger should divide the amount entered by covering the uncovered amounts of the invoices (invoice table) starting from the oldest invoice due date. Furthermore, if installment payments are envisaged, I would need to divide the amount also on any installments starting from the oldest installment due date.

like this function: https://andrewtuerk.wordpress.com/2013/01/17/splitting-allocations-across-multiple-records-in-a-single-statement/

or this: [SQL Server Allocation of amount in bill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860284/sql-server-allocation-of-amount-in-bill)

How can I activate a trigger when I insert row in table?

Many thanks,
Andrea.

Comment: *"How can I activate a trigger when I insert row in table?"* An `INSERT AFTER`/`INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger will *always* activate when you perform an `INSERT` against the table the trigger was created on. What are you actually asking here?

Comment: It's not generally a good idea to put what is actually fairly complicated business logic into the database, let alone doing that in a trigger. Keep your tables simple and write stored procedures instead (called by the clients in lieu of deceptively "simple" inserts); those can begin transactions as appropriate to keep data consistent. They also make it easy to later move (part of the) logic to the client side, if so desired -- proper testing and error handling tends to be much easier in languages that are not T-SQL.

Comment: Yeah trigger not a good solution for this. Stored procedure best solution for this problem.

Comment: You have code samples to do this - go implement it. Can it be done in a trigger? Yes. Is it a good idea to do that? Probably not - most "payment" interfaces show the result of the payment logic to the user **before** attempting an update to allow the user to verify and manipulate that allocation. Usually (and often legally) you generate a receipt - how will you do this as a part of your process when the app has no actual knowledge?